# "Could not find store" after wrapping component with context provider in Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, store

After wrapping a React Component with the appropriate provider, the store is still not found within the jest testing environment. Is there something that I am missing, or another cleaner way to go about this?

This is the practice that is functional for other stores, and I have used with other components, so I don't see a reason why this shouldn't work. The renderer should be creating an object wrapped with the TextContext that it needs to read from in order to populate fields.

Context

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import React, { createContext } from 'react';

export const TextContext = createContext({});

export function TextProvider({ children, text }) {
  return <TextContext.Provider value={text}>{children}</TextContext.Provider>;
}

export const TextConsumer = TextContext.Consumer;
```

```
function renderComposition(props) {
  const text = {
    ... // some text objects
  };
  return (
    <TextProvider text={text}>
      <Composition {...props} />
    </TextProvider>
  );
}
```

target failing line

```
beforeEach(() => {
...
   subject = mount(renderer.create(renderComposition(props)));
...
)};
```

with error of

```
Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Composition)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Composition)".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your component requires mocked store, you can provide it by creating  `mockReduxState.js`

```
import configureMockStore from "redux-mock-store";

export const createMockStore = state => configureMockStore()(state);
```

Updating the failing test by passing mockedStore.

```
beforeEach(() => {
...
 let updatedProp = {...props, store:createMockStore};
   subject = mount(renderer.create(renderComposition(updatedProp)));
...
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was unrelated, I was importing the component rather than the connected container, so the store was never getting set. Names are half of the battle turns out. The mocking the store option is also a great way to handle this  thanks paragxvii